# How do you use regex to remove potentially repeating patterns from the end of a string?

Tags: python, regex, google-api

Using the Google API to get emails from an inbox, the body of each email includes a section at the end which acts like a quote for what the email is replying to.  This pattern can repeat indefinitely depending on the length of chain of emails.

I am trying to get just the relevant message from the start of that string, before it goes into showing the replied to information.

An example pattern is:

**RELEVANT MESSAGE** On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:34 AM Some Name <some@email.com> wrote: **QUOTED MESSAGE** On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:33 AM <some_other@email.com> wrote: **PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE**

I would like to extract only the **RELEVANT MESSAGE**

I've tried a pattern like this, but it will greedily capture the first quoted message into the result.group(1)

```
result = re.search('(.*) On (.*), (.*),(.*) at (.*)', m['snippet'])
```

nets me:

```
result.group(1): RELEVANT MESSAGE On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:34 AM Some Name &lt;some@email.com&gt; wrote: QUOTED MESSAGE
result.group(2): On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:33 AM &lt;some_other@email.com&gt; wrote: PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE
```

What I would hope for is:

```
result.group(1): RELEVANT MESSAGE
result.group(2): On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:34 AM Some Name &lt;some@email.com&gt; wrote: QUOTED MESSAGE On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:33 AM &lt;some_other@email.com&gt; wrote: PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE
```

or:

```
result.group(1): RELEVANT MESSAGE
result.group(2): On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:34 AM Some Name &lt;some@email.com&gt; wrote: QUOTED MESSAGE
result.group(3): On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:33 AM &lt;some_other@email.com&gt; wrote: PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE
```

Comment: is the words `RELEVANT MESSAGE` , `QUOTED MESSAGE` , and `PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE` are in the message body itself?

Comment: You need better sample input for anyone to give a truly accurate reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract only RELEVANT MESSAGE

```
test="RELEVANT MESSAGE On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:34 AM Some Name <some@email.com> wrote: \
QUOTED MESSAGE On Thu, Apr 25, 2019 at 10:33 AM <some_other@email.com> wrote: \
PREVIOUS QUOTED MESSAGE"

result = re.search('(.*?)(?=On[^,]+,[^,]+,[ 0-9]+at)', test)

result.group(0): 'RELEVANT MESSAGE '
```

I think it's worth articulate a little on the regex pattern (in very colloquial terms):

(.*?) : the `?` at the end means 'non-greedy' otherwise it will try to match as much characters as possible (that's what is mainly happening in your regex pattern).

(?=...) : means "match what stays before ..., but not ...

[^,]+ : all characters except `,` (comma) which we want to save as a separator in `[^,]+,[^,]+,[ 0-9]+`